# Milne-Thomson circle theorem - Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I have a doubt about a step from a proof of the Milne-Thomson circle theorem. You can see the proof of the theorem [here](https://pt.scribd.com/doc/139393561/Milne-Thomson-Circle-Theorem) (I also saw the same proof written on a book of aerodynamics). My doubt is about the following proposition that was enunciated on that site:

$$f(z)+\bar{f}(\bar{z}) \text{ is a real number}$$

As far as I know, this proposition isn't true. The right proposition is $$f(z)+\bar{f}(z) \text{ is a real number}$$
which is easy to demonstrate.

So, imagine the example of a function $f(z)=z$: we have $\bar{f}(\bar{z})=\bar{\bar{z}}=z$, which makes $f(z)+\bar{f}(\bar{z})$ not real if $z$ isn't real.

So, was that step from the proof right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky. Notice that $\overline{f(z)}$ it's not the same of $\overline{f}  (z)$. $\overline{f}(z)$  is the conjugate function of $f(z)$, that is the same 
except with all constants replaced by their conjugates, so $\overline{f}(\overline z) = \overline{f(z)}$.

Comment: I think that you are right. But this seems a bit not intuitve. Why did they use such complications? Why  not for example, defining the complex potential by $W=f(z)+\bar{f}\left(\frac{a^2}{\bar{z}}\right)$ and use the definition $\bar{f}(z)=\overline{f(z)}$ which is the concept normally used on Mathematics?